# Magnitude of derivative and slope of secant between interval end points

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Problem: Given a non-linear function $f(x)$ which is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, prove that there exists a point $\eta \in (a,b)$ for which $$\vert f'(\eta)\vert \gt \vert\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\vert.$$
I only find a proof for a special case where $\vert f'(x)\vert$ is *everywhere continuous* (proof by contradiction):

Suppose that $\vert f'(x)\vert \leq \vert\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\vert , \forall x \in (a,b)$. Arbitrarily take a point $x_0\in(a,b)$. Then
\begin{align}
\vert f(b)-f(a) \vert
   &\leq \vert f(b)-f(x_0)\vert + \vert f(x_0)-f(a)\vert
\\ &= \vert f'(\xi'_1)\vert(b-x_0)+ \vert f'(\xi_1)\vert(x_0-a)
\\ &\leq \vert\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\vert (b-x_0)
       + \vert\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\vert(x_0-a)
\\ &= \vert f(b)-f(a)\vert
\end{align}

where $\xi_1\in(a,x_0)$ and $\xi'_1 \in (x_0,b)$.
So both $\vert f'(\xi_1)\vert$ and $\vert f'(\xi'_1)\vert$ must equal to $\vert\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\vert$.

Let $\zeta_1=\frac{x+\xi_1}{2}, \zeta'_1=\frac{x+\xi'_1}{2}$, using $\zeta_1$, $x_0$ and $\zeta'_1$ as splitting points of $[a,b]$ and following the same routine above, we can find $\xi_2\in(\zeta_1,x_0)$ and $\xi'_1\in(x_0,\zeta'_1)$ such that
$$\vert f'(\xi_2)\vert = \vert f'(\xi'_2)\vert = \vert\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\vert$$
  and meanwhile $0 < \xi'_2 - \xi_2 < \frac{1}{2}(\xi'_1 - \xi_1)$.

Repeat these steps, finally we obtain a series of nested intervals $[\xi_n,\xi'_n]$, all of which contain $x_0$ and whose size shrink to $0$ and hence
 has $x_0$ as limit, satisfying
$$\vert f'(\xi_n)\vert = \vert f'(\xi'_n)\vert = \vert\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\vert.$$

Since $\vert f'(x) \vert$ is continuous, $\vert f'(x_0) \vert$ also equals to
$\vert\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\vert$.
Therefore, $\vert f'(x) \vert = \vert\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\vert = constant$ and
$f(x)$ must be a linear function, wihch contradicts with the condition, finishing the proof.

But how to tackle the problem if $\vert f'(x) \vert$ is discontinuous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $L =\dfrac{\left| f(b)-f(a)\right|}{b-a} $. Suppose, to the contrary, that $|f'|\le L$ everywhere on $(a,b)$. By the mean value theorem,
for every $x\in (a,b)$ we have 
$$|f(x)-f(a)|\le L(x-a) \tag{1}$$
and
$$|f(b)-f(x)|\le L(b-x) \tag{2}$$
Adding (1) and (2) gives
$$|f(x)-f(a)|+|f(x)-f(a)| \le L(b-a) = |f(b)-f(a)| \tag{3}$$
The triangle inequality goes in the direction opposite to (3). Thus, (3) holds as an equality. Consequently, equality holds in (1) and (2)
as well.

But the only number $y$ that satisfies both
$$|y-f(a)| = L(x-a) \tag{1'}$$
and
$$|f(b)-y| = L(b-x) \tag{2'}$$
is
$$y = f(a)+\frac{x-a}{b-a}(f(b)-f(a))\tag{4}$$
Indeed, if (4) holds, then (1') and (2') hold (check by plugging in). The only other value of $y$ that has the same $|y-f(a)|$ is
$$ f(a)-\frac{x-a}{b-a}(f(b)-f(a)) $$
but then  $|y-f(b)|$ is too big.